# Oracle query to fetch the previous value of a related row in same table

Tags: oracle

I have a table Student which has name and ratings year wise.

```
Name    Year    Rating

Ram    2016      10
Sam    2016      9
Ram    2014      8
Sam    2012      7
```

I need to find the previous rating of the employee which could be last year or some years before.

The query should return below results

```
Name    Cur_rating_year_2016    Prev_rating
Ram               10            8
Sam                9            7
```

Below is the script for insert and create

```
Create table Student (name varchar2(10), year number, rating number  );
insert into student values('Ram' ,2016 ,10);
insert into student values('Sam' ,2016 ,9);
insert into student values('Sam' ,2012 ,7);
insert into student values('Ram' ,2014 ,8);
```

Is there a way to achieve this using select query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `LAG` analytical function https://docs.oracle.com/database/122/SQLRF/LAG.htm#SQLRF00652

> LAG is an analytic function. It provides access to more than one row
>   of a table at the same time without a self join. Given a series of
>   rows returned from a query and a position of the cursor, LAG provides
>   access to a row at a given physical offset prior to that position.
>
> For the optional offset argument, specify an integer that is greater
>   than zero. If you do not specify offset, then its default is 1. The
>   optional default value is returned if the offset goes beyond the scope
>   of the window. If you do not specify default, then its default is
>   null.

```
SELECT stud_name AS name, 
       r_year AS year,
       r_value AS rating,
       lag(r_value, 1, NULL) OVER(PARTITION BY stud_name ORDER BY r_year) AS prev_rating
  FROM stud_r
 ORDER BY stud_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try as:

```
SELECT A.NAME,A.RATING,B.RATING  FROM 
    STUDENTS A INNER JOIN STUDENTS B 
    ON A.NAME=B.NAME  
    WHERE A.YEAR='2016' AND B.YEAR<>'2016'
    ORDER BY A.NAME ASC
```